# Flutter 2.0 : TextField and decimal

Tags: flutter, textfield

With Flutter 2.0 and  textfield, I would like the result to always be displayed with 2 decimal places even if there is only one decimal entered by the user.

Anyone know the trick?

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                                onChanged: (val) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    totalxx = double.tryParse(val);
                                  });
                                },
```

Comment: I know that doubles in dart have a method called `toStringAsFixed` and you can pass the number of decimal places you want. For example if you have `double a = 5.4` and write `a.toStringAsFixed(2)`, and you will get `5.40` as a string.

Comment: Thanks Andrej for taking the time to answer me. Indeed I know this method which I use in Text widgets when necessary but in this example it does not work ...